# laravel schedule task to run every 10 days of a month

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a task which I need to execute for the first 10 days of every month

something like below:

```
$schedule->command('log:test')->cron('* * 1-10 * *');
```

seems `cron()` is not getting executed... though `everyMinute()` is working fine...  How can I get this to work?

Comment: You're looking for `0 0 1-10 * * *`, not `* * 1-10 * * *`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to fill the hour and minutes on the cron.
Try this one if you want it get executed at the start of the day.

```
$schedule->command('log:test')->cron('0 0 1-10 * *');
```