# How to run laravel cron after every 2 weeks or 14 days

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I need to run laravel cron for after every 2 weeks or 14 days. but not found any solution for this.
I was also search on laravel documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling
and found this option

```
->weekly();
```

But it runs on weekly.
I was search also other option and found this
[laravel schedule task to run every 10 days of a month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33019475/laravel-schedule-task-to-run-every-10-days-of-a-month)
But it work only first 10 days of a month

```
$schedule->command('log:test')->cron('0 0 1-10 * *');
```

Please help me if you have any solution thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this: `$schedule->command('log:test')->cron('0 0 0 1,15 * ?');` Let me know if this works!

Comment: i think it's work only for after 14 day of a month but i need after every 14 day

Comment: This expression which will trigger every 15 days. Can you plz test it? You can change the first three zeroes to fire them at a particular time you want!

Comment: ok thanks i will try this and reply you it's  working or not

Comment: Ok, no problem :) I think you can test it using changing the dates.

Comment: @ankit you want to hit the cron after 14 days or on 14 day and is it related to monthly basis or every 14 day

Comment: Do you want to work on live host..? Then you have to add a cron job on your server

Comment: @ankit Is my code works? Please let me know. So that i can post my answer! :)

Comment: @saurabh i need run cron after 14 days or on 14 days the days will be change but not for monthly basis.

Comment: @ankit Can you please let me know it works or not?

Comment: @Hiren can you tell me how can i test this code for now? means it for 14 days

Comment: I am not sure, but i think you can test it with changing the dates in your system!

Comment: Is my answer fixed your problem?? Can you please let me know?

Comment: no it's not working.

Comment: Any errors you got?

Answer (score 6):

```
$schedule->command('command_name')->weekly()->mondays()
         ->when(function () {
             return date('W') % 2;
          })->at("13:38");
```

Function will return 1 in every two other weeks, So the command will be called in every two weeks.

Comment: From all the answers this one is the most intuitive and yet flexible to configure.

I wanted to run the cron job only on alternate saturdays, but didn't know such day methods existed in laravel. Thank you for this!

Answer (score 4):

You can use daily() together with when() method and inside when add suitable constrain for your task. For example, run task every month on 1,16 days:

```
$schedule->command('sitemap:sitemap_xml_generate')->daily()->when(function () {
$days = [1,16];
$today = Carbon::today();
return in_array($today->day, $days);});
```

or you can use  this

```
$schedule->command('sitemap:sitemap_xml_generate')->cron('0 0 1,16 * *');
```

cron('0 0 1,16 * *') -> Argument are 'minute hour day(we can specify multiple date seperated by comma) month year'

Answer (score 0):

```
$schedule->command('log:test')->cron('0 0 */14 * *');
```

2017-09-15 00:00:00

2017-09-29 00:00:00

2017-10-01 00:00:00

2017-10-15 00:00:00

2017-10-29 00:00:00

or you can run your custom

```
    $schedule->command('log:test')->weekly()->when(function () {
        return ((Carbon::now()->day % 2) === 1); //bool only for example
    });
```